# Patch Not Working

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, patch-data

Patch File: Bedard/CustomGloves/Setup/Patch/Data

```
<?php

namespace Bedard\CustomGloves\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;

class SetupCustomGloveProductAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchVersionInterface
{
    /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /** @var EavSetupFactory */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'alternative_color', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Alternative Color',
            'input' => 'select',
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Getting this error on setup:upgrade

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Bedard\CustomGloves\Setup\Patch\Data\SetupCustomGloveProductAttribute' not found in /home/customer/www/dom2sandbox.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchRegistry.php on line 141

PatchRegistry:

```
    /**
    * Get patch dependencies.
    *
    * @param string $patch
    * @return string[]
    */
   private function getDependencies(string $patch)
   {
       $depInstances = [];
       $deps = call_user_func([$patch, 'getDependencies']);
       $this->cyclomaticStack[$patch] = true;

       foreach ($deps as $dep) {
           if (isset($this->cyclomaticStack[$dep])) {
               throw new \LogicException("Cyclomatic dependency during patch installation");
           }

           $depInstance = $this->registerPatch($dep);
           /**
            * If a patch already have applied dependency - then we definitely know
            * that all other dependencies in dependency chain are applied too, so we can skip this dep
            */
           if (!$depInstance) {
               continue;
           }

           $depInstances = array_replace($depInstances, $this->getDependencies($this->patches[$dep]));
           $depInstances[$depInstance] = $depInstance;
       }

       unset($this->cyclomaticStack[$patch]);
       return $depInstances;
   }
```

2.3.3 Community Edition

Comment: PatchVersionInterface is deprecated. Also in your patch is missing the getVersion method implementation. Try to remove the implementation of PatchVersionInterface

Comment: Check the namespace is correct. In my case, this error came up because the path's namespace was Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\. Note the different, the way right is Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data\

Answer (score 0):

Seems like issue with not implemented Interface method. If the issue persist after implementation is fixed then the next possible issue is file name.